# Moving Azure resource to new subscription - Migrating from BizSpark to BizSpark Plus

Tags: azure, cloud, bizspark

I am trying to move all my current Azure services to my new Azure BizSpark Plus account. Following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources), there is this little note that needs to be checked before the move (see image below):

> I understand that tools and scripts associated with moved resources will not work until I update them to use new resource IDs

[image]

What does this mean? Will I have to update my Azure API keys or Azure script URL in my client apps? Should I expect a downtime? How can I update the 'tools and scripts' to use the 'new resource ID'?

*Note: the little exclamation mark lead back to the same article mentioned above.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDs for your resources are in the format:

`resource/subscriptions/[subscription id]/resourceGroups/[resource group name]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/[app name]/appServices`

As you can see, the resource group name is part of that unique Id, so moving it to a new resource group changes that Id.

The warning is simply stating that if you currently have any tools or scripts that reference the resource using the old resource group name, they will need to be updated to the use the new Id.

Comment: Should I expect my client apps to go down if I did not update the 'resource ID'? is the 'resource ID' update a manual process? Is my Azure services (ex: App Service) considered to be 'tools and scripts'? If yes, then I should expect my Azure services to go down, right?

Comment: Most likely not, but it depends. For instance, your application is probably accessing the SQL database using a connection string that has the IP address and accessing the web app using the *.azurewebsite.net domain name or your own domain name. In my two examples, the application would not go down.